# why am i getting random NAN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is shift 48 values.

I check the `numpy` array and it seems fine: by that I mean it is shifted 48 places. Now I want to split the data of the dataframe to a 70:30 ratio so that all the lines with `nan` values are in the 30 percent part.

Now when I print `x_train` I get some of the lines with `nan` values for some reason but I can't seem to figure what is wrong with my code.

**PS** data is a dataframe provided by the api used and does not provide `nan` values

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

## the index is the date and the columns are as prediction,strength,k,g,w
x = np.array(dff.drop(['prediction','strength','g'],1))
y = np.array(dff.drop(['prediction','strength','k'],1))

x_train, x_test, y_train,t_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.3)
```

When I try to print `x_train` I get the values I need but some of them are `nan` values for `'strength'` and `'g'`.

I am spliting the data the right way and after spliting the data does it get sorted in any way.

part of `x_train` output:

```
[78.90399933         nan         nan]
[75.04682159 8.51200104 8.16529846]
[78.07499695         nan         nan]
[81.23899841 9.76999664 9.13999939]
[80.60099792 8.34100342 8.07700348]
[79.50131226         nan         nan]
[72.7118988  4.44860077 7.51000214]
[79.55729675         nan         nan]
[74.17259979 5.2460022  7.83300018]
[74.11289978 4.3219986  7.40000153]
[79.62058258         nan         nan]
```

My request is to output the data without the `nan` values.

Comment: Can you show us `df .head(5)`? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the data is shuffled before splitting. So, if you would like to split data without any randomness, you should set `shuffle=False` in `train_test_split`.